# How to publish an application in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, installation

I'm working on a small console application in Visual Studio C++ 2008 and would like to make an installer that I can distribute to a few friends to test the application.  I recall a publish option being under the build menu, but it is not there now.  Could I somehow have turned this feature off?

Is there a simple way to publish such that my application will be relatively independent of Windows Version?

Thanks,

Nerf42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build the exec program, make sure you include all the needed libraries.
Then you can use installcreator and create simple setup program.

Answer (score 2):

[Deploying Your Program (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can only publish Web projects. If you want an installer package for a console application, you will need to create a setup project.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error:  Publish is available for Visual Studio C# projects, Visual Studio C++ projects have no such option.

Thanks to all who answered.

=-N42-=